# Is predeclaring variables always necessary?

Tags: c#, dictionary, scope

Maybe kinda silly question, but what is syntax wise the way to go in c#?
if I retrieve values from a dictionary and I am not sure if they exist, do I need to predeclare these, so if they exist I can use m later on?

Example (I need to use 'string bla' later on in the code):

```
string bla = null;
if (myDictionary.ContainsKey("unknownKey"))
{
    bla = myDictionary["unknownKey"];
}

if (bla != null) {  etc etc etc }
```

I do have to check a lot of items in a dictionary, also some more complex types, so that's gonna be a rather large predeclaration ...

But I think in this case asking the question is answering it ...

Comment: you can create `Dictionary<string, string> defaultDictionary =  new Dictionary<string,string> {{"unknownKey", "unknownValue"}, ...};` and a helper method `string GetValue(string key) { if (myDictionary.Contains(key)) {return myDictionary[key]; } return defaultDictionary[key]; }`

Comment: It is always required to *declare* the variable. It is further necessary to *initialize* the variable if the variable otherwise wouldn’t be initialized (e.g. if the condition wasn’t true in your case). The compiler will require this and tell you whenever you forget it. So the answer is: It is necessary when the compiler requires it.

Comment: to add to pokes answer: you do initialize it. With null. This is totally valid.

Comment: In the upcoming C# 7.0 there is syntax improvement for this case. Check out [C# 7.0 out var declaration](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/1936/c-sharp-7-0-features/6326/out-var-declaration#t=201608230750429106106)

Answer (score 5):

For stuff like that I like to use extension methods:

```
public static class DictionaryExtensions
{
    public static T1 ValueOrDefault<T, T1>(this IDictionary<T, T1> dictionary, T key)
    {
        if (key == null || dictionary == null)
            return default(T1);

        T1 value;
        return dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out value) ? value : default(T1);
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
var bla = myDictionary.ValueOrDefault("unknownKey");
```

Comment: This may make a nice way to retrieve the value but it does not answer the question at all (about whether or when it’s necessary).

Comment: Allowing the dictionary to be null is a mistake imo. Normally, calling methods on a null reference would throw an exception, but there is this extension method feature that can indeed (sort of) omit the issue, but that seems wrong anyway.

Comment: @poke I interpreted the goal of Ronald to be able to access the dictionary without having to check whether the key is present in the dictionary first. One way to do so would be to set the values to some default value. I would recommend against doing so and instead use such an extension method which hides the code to check for an existing key and makes the code more readable. Of course you could also add your own default value to the extension method.

Comment: @Silvermind I am not sure what would be the best approach in this case. I guess this depends on the rest of the code and whether it is acceptable to continue execution in case the dictionary is `null`. But you definitely have a point.

Answer (score 5):

I'd prefer this

```
    if (myDictionary.ContainsKey("unknownKey"))
    {
        var bla = myDictionary["unknownKey"];
        //etc etc etc
    }
    else
    {
        //your code when the key doesn't exist
        //sometimes this else is useless
    }
```

**Note that Dictionary(K,V) can have null values!** Imagine

```
myDictionary.Add("unknownKey", null);
```

**EDIT** Generally speaking, checking `bla == null` is not the same as `myDictionary.ContainsKey` because the value can still be `null` even the key exists. For a better performance, you should always use `.TryGetValue` like this:

```
    string bla;
    if (myDictionary.TryGetValue("unknownKey", out bla))
    {
        //the key exists
    }
    else
    {
        //the key doesn't exist
    }
```

Comment: This does require 2 lookups where 1 is enough. TryGetValue() could solve this and make the difference between not-found and found-null.

Comment: @HenkHolterman But `1 lookup` is `O(1)`. `TryGetValue()` is great, but looks ugly because you need to declare the `out` variable outside of the scope, like what OP did in the question.

Comment: @HenkHolterman The most pretty solution is removed in C#6 RC, `myDictionary.TryGetValue("key", out var bla)`, that's a pity.

Comment: It’s only *amortized* constant time. It’s still possible for individual keys to trigger a linear time complexity (e.g. for hash collisions). So if you know you need to check *and* extract it anyway, use `TryGetValue` directly.

Comment: @poke Makes sense. I'll add the comments into the answer.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that no one has actually answered your question.

Yes, predeclaring the variable is always necessary. What you can choose is the scope of the variable, but little else.

For example, this would be an alternative:

```
if (myDictionary.ContainsKey("unknownKey"))
{
    var bla = myDictionary["unknownKey"];

    if (bla != null) {  etc etc etc }
}

var bla = "someother string"; //valid because previous bla declaration is out of scope.
```

C# requires that all variables be declared *and* initialized before they are used. Sometimes initialization is done automatically for you (instance fields) but there is no way around having to declare them.

Comment: @poke duh! yes, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Variables need to be declared in order to be able to use them. The declaration needs to happen at a scope level that still applies to the usage. So in your case, you could not declare the string `bla` inside the `if` since outside of it, it wouldn’t be accessible so you couldn’t use `bla` afterwards.

In addition to the declaration, the C# compiler requires you to *initialize* variables before you can access them. This is a safety measure to make sure that the variable actually has some *meaningful* value. An initialization can be any valid assignment, including proper values, dummy values or the default value of the type.

For reference types, e.g. strings, a common initialization value that would later be replaced would be `null`. So what you are doing already is pretty common practice.

So in your case, since you assign a value to the variable only within the `if` but use it afterwards, you need to initialize the variable with some value first. Otherwise, consider the following:

```
string bla; // not initialized

if (someCondition)
{
    bla = "some value";
}

Console.WriteLine(bla);
```

If `someCondition` is true, then everything is fine. `bla` has an actual value, so it can be printed. However, if the condition is not true, then `bla` is never assigned any value—it is not initialized. The compiler will detect this possibility of the variable never getting initialized and tell you to fix it. So above code is not allowed. You need to initialize the `bla` string first, e.g. with `null` as you did.

In general, you need to initialize a variable whenever the compiler tells you to do so. If there is no possible path where a variable would not get initialized, then you do not need to initialize it explicitly. For example, if you added an `else` case to the above code where the variable gets assigned some value, everything would be fine:

```
string bla; // not initialized

if (someCondition)
{
    bla = "some value";
}
else
{
    bla = "some other value";
}

Console.WriteLine(bla);
```

---

For your particular problem, retrieving a value from a dictionary *if it exists*, you could use [`Dictionary.TryGetValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013.aspx). This method allows you to check for a key and retrieve the value at the same time. So you only have a single dictionary lookup. It uses an `out` parameter to retrieve the value, so you could do it like this:

```
string bla;
dictionary.TryGetValue("unknownKey", out bla);

Console.WriteLine(bla);
```

Note that since `bla` is passed as an `out` parameter, you do not need to initialize it. This is because methods using an `out` parameter are already *required* to initialize it. So even if the key does not exist in the dictionary, `bla` has an initialized value. In the case of `TryGetValue`, it will receive the type’s default value then (for strings, this is `null`).

Of course, the more common use is to use the return value of `TryGetValue` to get some feedback whether a key existed as you retrieve it from the dictionary:

```
string bla;
if (dictionary.TryGetValue("unknownKey", out bla))
{
    // key existed
    // do something with bla
}
```